# Subscript on the bottom and Superscript on the top

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, superscripts

I am writing an equation and I want that subscript should be in the center bottom and superscript should be on the center top of the symbol instead of bottom and top sides. I tried to use the `\underset` command but it only places subscript at the desired place but not the superscript

A minimal working example is given below:

```
      \documentclass{paper}
      \usepackage{amsthm}
      \usepackage{amsmath}
      \usepackage{mathptmx}
      \usepackage{mathrsfs}
      \begin{document}
      \begin{equation}
      \underset{0}{S}^{q} = f\Bigg\{\dfrac{SE}{TA}\Bigg\}  
      \label{eq:incrS}
      \end{equation}
      \end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure what you desire, but does declaring `\DeclareMathOperator*{\Soperator}{S}` in the preamble and then using `\Soperator_{0}^{q}` do what you want?

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you. It worked perfectly. I only added `\mathit` along with the command suggested by you in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\operatorname*` to get limits positioning of the sub and super script, but also you should almost never use `\big` sequence of commands they are really just part of the implementation of the open and close form `\bigl` and `\bigr`. `Bigg` seems much too big here, I'd use `Big` although some might use the intermediate `bigg` size. Also `\dfrac` isn't needed I just used `\frac` (which makes the same output in this case)

[image]

```
  \documentclass{paper}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{mathptmx}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
  \operatorname*{S}_0^{q} = f\Bigl\{\frac{SE}{TA}\Bigr\}  
  \label{eq:incrS}
  \end{equation}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: To the OP: don’t overlook a subtle difference between this answer and [Sandy G’s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361533/69818): here the “S” character is upright.  This may, or may not, be what you want.  **Edit:** This remark was partially inspired by [your comment above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361520/subscript-on-the-bottom-and-superscript-on-the-top#comment891314_361520).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `\overset` together with `\underset`. Try the code

```
\overset{q}{\underset{0}{S}}
```

to replace

```
\underset{0}{S}^{q}
```

[image]